# Errorbars matplotliby python

Tags: python, matplotlib

i would like to know how i can add errorbars to my plot. Im attaching pic of code and plot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/filWW.png)

Comment: Please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71460342/edit) your code as text, never as image.

Comment: Did you check the [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/errorbar_limits_simple.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-errorbar-limits-simple-py)? Did you try that code? Did you decide about how you want to represent the errors? Which problems did you encounter?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.